# web deploy 401 from package, works in VS2010

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

I'm trying to get an automated deployment working from a CI server (TFS 2010)
Basically I've got a package getting built and if all the tests past I'd like to deploy it.

Outside of TFS and just using the visual studio command line, I navigate to the folder location of the package and use the following:

```
 C:\site\Package>site.deploy.cmd /Y 
 /M:"https://WebServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd" -allowUntrusted /U:username 
 /P:password /A:Basic
```

Where in this case the user is a domain user with full permissions on the destination website folder. When I run this I get a 401 unauthorized error. I've created an IIS Manager and set up the permissions for the network service account on the destination files too but that also gives the same error.

The frustrating point is that from the VS 2010 right mouse click publish page it works perfectly with either user. Does anyone have any ideas. I've been all over stack overflow and I'm certain that the folder permissions are correct and that IIS is configured correctly. The fact that VS 2010 can publish with the same credentials backs that up for me.
I did see that you can pass ?site=SiteName when specifying the server but I just get errors about not expecting that parameter.

Looking at the site.deploy.cmd and site.SetParameters.xml it appears that it certainly looks likes it's going for Web Deploy 2 and that the configuration settings have been correctly grabbed from the config transform.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's a non-admin user, you need to include the IIS site in the remote URL.

```
C:\site\Package>site.deploy.cmd /Y /M:"https://WebServer:8172/MsDeploy.axd?site=Website Name" -allowUntrusted /U:username /P:password /A:Basic
```

It's possible the generated cmd file does this for you, but only when you supply a certain argument.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.jrjlee.com/2011/12/deploying-web-packages-as-non.html

this may work. append your site name with querystring to your url